# How do you debug iOS device on windows?

Tags: ios, windows

I have some strange behavior where something doesn't work on iOS only, but works on any other device. I tried to debug. I've tried this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-ios-web-debug, but doesn't work with 12.1+ iOS version.

What is the alternative to test this on windows?

Comment: to debug it you need iOS, there's no other option

Comment: @Raphael I have iPhone you are saying i need Mac?

Comment: yes, to debug iPhone you need Mac as this is its natural environment

Comment: :( same problem here . might i am gonna buy mac

Answer (score 0):

Use an enhanced lldb to support debugging non-jailbroken iOS device on Window, like this [ios lldb windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBMOp.png)